# CSS: how to get class inside class

Tags: html, css

I am making a dropdown on hover, but I have a problem with CSS. I have class inside class inside a div etc. The problem is that the dropdown list doesn't show. I think that I am doing something wrong with CSS selectors.

This is html code:

```
<div id="header">
   <div class="row-2">                      
      <ul class="hover">
         <li><a href="index.php" class="active">Home</a></li>
         <li><a>Pershkrimi</a>
             <div class="button">
                <ul class="file_menu">
                   <li>klzxd</li>                           
                </ul>
            </div>                                  
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="trailer.php">Trailera</a>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="categories.php">Kategorite</a>
        </li>   
        <li class="last">
           <a href="sitemap.html">Sitemap</a>
        </li>                       
      </ul>
   </div>                       
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header .row-2  {
    height:51px;
}

#header .row-2 ul {
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#header .row-2 ul li  {
    float:left;
    font-size:20px;
    line-height:2.4em;
    margin-right:5px;
    background-color:#000;
}

#header .row-2 ul li.last  {
    margin-right:0;
}

#header .row-2 ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#f0f0f0;width:184px;
    height:56px;float:left;
    background-image:url(images/nav-bg.gif);b
    ackground-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    text-align:center;
}

#header .row-2 ul li a:hover, #header .row-2 ul li a.active {
    color:#d72a18;
    background-image:url(images/nav-act.gif);
}

/*Dropdown*/
 #header .row-2 ul li div.button {
    height: 32px;
    width: 184px;
    margin: auto;
}
 #header .row-2 ul li div.button ul, li {
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    list-style: none;
}
 #header .row-2 ul li div.button ul .file_menu {
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}

 #header .row-2 ul li div.button ul.file_menu li {
    background-color: #302f2f;
}

 #header .row-2 ul li div.button ul .file_menu li a {
    color:#FFFFFF; 
    text-decoration:none; 
    padding:10px; 
    display:block;
}

 #header .row-2 ul li div.button ul .file_menu li a:hover {
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #F00880;
}
```

/*SLIDESHOW*/

```
#slogan 
{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
    background:url(images/banner-bg.gif) no-repeat left top;
    color:#1d1d1d
}
#slogan .image 
{
    position:absolute;
    right:-30px;
    top:-11px;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow: hidden; 
    background:url(images/banner-img.png) no-repeat left top
}
#slogan p 
{
    margin-bottom:23px
}
#slogan .inside 
{
    padding:  0 0 25px;
    width:939px
}
#page1 #content .box 
{
    margin:0
}
#page1 #header .row-2 ul li a 
{
    height:56px
}
#page1 #header .row-2 ul li.last a:hover 
{
    position:relative;z-index:2
}
.slideshow
{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:332px;   
}
.slideshow img
{
    position:absolute;
    left:4px;
    top:10px;       
}
```

NOTE: I just added slideshow CSS, that i think is overwriting dropdown
Thank You,

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zjKdA/ ?

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. Your description needs to be more specific. Also, a jsfiddle would be nice.

Comment: @Marcel Gwerder I am trying to get something like this http://jsfiddle.net/k24SL/

Comment: But the problem is that this list is inside an other list with different style

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with the different style?

Comment: The problem is that the first menu with listed elements is displayed, but the dropdown menu that is inside list "Pershkrimi", doesn't show. I have done something wrong with selectors. Because when i drop the first menu style, the dropdown menu is displayed. Am I more clear now?

Comment: You set `.file_menu` to `display: none;` once and never change it. So it's of course hidden. Either I'm missing something or you are missing a hover state with a `display: block;` or something like that.

Comment: I just found that the problem is that it is having a crash with slideshow. I will add my slideshow CSS, please take a look, because I can't find out why slideshow overwrite my dropdown.

Comment: I still don't think that it's a problem with overridden styles. You hide your submenu in the following selector `#header .row-2 ul li div.button ul .file_menu`. Where do you make it visible again?

Comment: When i deleted my slideshow ,submenu was exactly like I wanted. And I tried also display:block but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things I would do differently with how you've got your CSS laid out, but if you're looking for a simple answer, use the `>` [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) instead of just a space in order to select only those lists that are in your `row-2` class.  For example,

```
#header .row-2>ul
```

will get only `<ul>` elements whose parent is a `.row-2` element, which seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Can I do something like this : #row-2> div>ul>li>ul>.file_menu

Comment: You could, and that would work for what you have now.